# Custom Taxonomy Template Variables Available?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I have a custom Taxonomy sports and want to edit the front-end display. I have got taxonomy-sports.php and used this code to get the data on the taxonomy, but I feel like it should already be available? Is there a simpler way to do this or is going into $wp_query the way to go?

```
$sport_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['sports'];
$the_sport = get_term_by( 'slug', $sport_slug, 'sports', ARRAY_A );
print_r($the_sport);
```

Basically I understand http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display but don't exactly know what is available to me and the best way to get to my taxonomy data on taxonomy-{sometax}.php

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer I was looking for as this:

`$sport_slug = get_query_var('term');`